# Is derived table executed once or three times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> Every time you make use of a derived table, that query is going to be executed. When using a CTE, that result set is pulled back once and only once within a single query.

Does the quote suggest that the following query will cause derived table to be executed three times ( once for each aggregate function’s call ):

```
  SELECT 
    AVG(OrdersPlaced),MAX(OrdersPlaced),MIN(OrdersPlaced)
  FROM (
    SELECT
        v.VendorID,
        v.[Name] AS VendorName,
        COUNT(*) AS OrdersPlaced
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS poh
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.Vendor AS v ON poh.VendorID = v.VendorID
    GROUP BY v.VendorID, v.[Name]
  ) AS x
```

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, but it may spool the derived results so it only needs to access it once.

In this case, there should be no difference between a CTE and derived table.

Where is the quote from?

Comment: "Where is the quote from?" http://facility9.com/2008/12/09/a-quick-introduction-to-common-table-expressions

Comment: "but it may spool the derived results so it only needs to access it once." What do you mean by spool?

Comment: It may generate an internal temp table so avoid 3 reads of the derived table. "spool" is the step you'll see in a query plan

Comment: BTW, that link isn't very good. His "ugly" example is unnecessary and can be done with one derived table. A CTE just makes it look nicer, that's all. CTEs can also kill performance http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/tags/CTE/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No that should be one pass, take a look at the execution plan

here is an example where something will run for every row in table table2

```
    select *,(select COUNT(*) from table1 t1 where t1.id <= t2.id) as Bla
     from table2 t2
```

Stuff like this with a running counts will fire for each row in the table2  table

Answer (score 2):

CTE or a nested (uncorrelated) subquery will generally have no different execution plan.  Whether a CTE or a subquery is used has never had an effect on my intermediate queries being spooled.

With regard to the Tony Rogerson link - the explicit temp table performs better than the self-join to the CTE because it's indexed better - many times when you go beyond declarative SQL and start to anticipate the work process for the engine, you can get better results.

Sometimes, the benefit of a simpler and more maintainable query with many layered CTEs instead of a complex multi-temp-table process outweighs the performance benefits of a multi-table process.  A CTE-based approach is a single SQL statement, which cannot be as quietly broken by a step being accidentally commented out or a schema changing.